# Вывод ключа по его индексу

Tags: массивы, php, индексы

Пример такой:
Есть массив

> $a = array(aaa => 'odin', bbb => 'dva', vvv => 'tri');

вывести первое значение массива можно двумя способами:

> echo $a[0]; // индекс '0' выводит "odin"
>
> echo $a['aaa']; // ключ 'aaa' выводит "odin"

То есть значение можно вызвать и по ключу и по индексу.

А вопрос такой:
Есть какая нибудь функция, которая по индексу выведет ключ массива? Что-то типа:

> echo *функция*($a[0]); // Выводит 'aaa'

p.s. Все глаза стер в поисковиках.

Comment: Это точно php? А какая версия? У меня вполне ожидаемо на echo $a[0]; php сругался Undefined offset.
У меня PHP 5.3.10

Comment: То, что Вы ищите невозможно ни в какой версии PHP.  
Код:  

    echo $a[0]; // индекс '0' выводит "odin"
    echo $a['aaa']; // ключ 'aaa' выводит "odin"
ошибочен, потому что ааа и 0 это два разных индекса. В PHP есть только один вид массива- ассоциативный в котором нет разницы целочисленный ли ключ или строковый.

Comment: Да. Вы оба правы. Прошу прощения, меня завело в заблуждение функция mysql_fetch_array(). Именно ей я создавал массив, и именно она создавала одинаковые значения и для $a[0], и для $a['aaa']. Т.е. в массиве были дублируемые значения. Array ( [0] => odin, [aaa] => odin, [1] => dva, [bbb] => dva, [2] => tri, [vvv] => tri). 
Спасибо, именно благодаря вам я пришел к верному умозаключению.

Comment: Так может быть Вы просто неправильно сформулировали вопрос? И Вас интересует, как узнать имя поля в ответе Mysql по индексу поля? Если так, то это будет совсем другой разговор. Такие функции есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```
$array = array('first' => 'A',
               'second'  => 'B',
               'third' => 'C');
$keys = array_keys($array);
echo $keys[0]; // first
```

Comment: Именно такой вариант я использовал, но я искал конкретную функцию. По причине отсутствия такой функции, этот ответ принимаю верным, ибо из него можно сделать свою function($index);

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(aaa => 'odin', bbb => 'dva', vvv => 'tri');
$key = array_search('odin', $a);
```

в ответе получим 'aaa' т.е. индекс элемента ассоциативного массива

Comment: Не индекс а ключ.
Такая схема мне не подойдет, поскольку в моем массиве есть множество повторяющихся значений. Нужно именно вывод ключа по индексу, а не по его значению.

Comment: да эта функция выведет ключ первого найденного элемента. Тогда только перебор значений как писали выше.